# Cannot scale svg if created with js

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to create svg image using Javascript. It has to be scaled to container size. I'm using viewport to define image size, and trying to scale it using width/height. Issue is fact that it is not working if it has been created from js.
You can see it here [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/0sLbo11m/2/)

Dont know why lines don't scale image

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 600);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive and the correct name of the attribute is viewBox and not viewbox as you've written it. What you actually want is this...

```
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', viewbox);
```

Using setAttribute instead of setAttributeNS and passing null as the first argument as I've done above would save you some typing.